# Loop dependencis when parallelizing loops with OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I tried parallelizing the following loop:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(v, g, p)
    for (i=1; i<=imax-1; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=jmax-1; j++) {  // combined loops
            /* only if both adjacent cells are fluid cells */
            if ((flag[i][j] & C_F) && (flag[i][j+1] & C_F)) {
                v[i][j] = g[i][j]-(p[i][j+1]-p[i][j])*del_t/dely;
            }
            if ((flag[i][j] & C_F) && (flag[i+1][j] & C_F)) {
                u[i][j] = f[i][j]-(p[i+1][j]-p[i][j])*del_t/delx;
            }
        }
    }
```

But my program does not run as expected, probably because of loop dependencies. Is there a way to parallelize this loop with reductions?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> But my program does not run as expected, probably because of loop
> dependencies. Is there a way to parallelize this loop with reductions?

There is a *race-condition* in one of the shared variables (i.e., the loop iterator `j`) being updated concurrently by multiple threads.

```
   #pragma omp parallel for shared(v, g, p)
   for (i=1; i<=imax-1; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=jmax-1; j++) {  // <---- Race-condition 
            /* only if both adjacent cells are fluid cells */
            if ((flag[i][j] & C_F) && (flag[i][j+1] & C_F)) {
                v[i][j] = g[i][j]-(p[i][j+1]-p[i][j])*del_t/dely;
            }
            if ((flag[i][j] & C_F) && (flag[i+1][j] & C_F)) {
                u[i][j] = f[i][j]-(p[i+1][j]-p[i][j])*del_t/delx;
            }
        }
    }
```

The variable `i` of the outermost loop does not have a *race-condition* because it belongs to the loop being parallelized, and in that case, the OpenMP standard states that that variable will be implicitly private.

To solve the *race-condition* you need to make the variable `j` of the innermost loop private. Either by doing:

```
   #pragma omp parallel for shared(v, g, p) private(j)
   for (i=1; i<=imax-1; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=jmax-1; j++) {
```

or (depending in your compiler version):

```
   #pragma omp parallel for shared(v, g, p)
   for (i=1; i<=imax-1; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=jmax-1; j++) {
```

Comment: A nicer way to do this is to move into the 1990s and declare your variables in their minimal scope. That frequently avoids the incorrect sharing of inner scope variables with no extra effort, as well as making the code easier to read.